# how to grab all the owners of a name

Tags: c#, linq

I have one plain class data like,

```
var data = new List<PlainData>
            {
                new PlainData {Name = "A", Owner = "X"},
                new PlainData {Name = "A", Owner = "Y"},
                new PlainData {Name = "B", Owner = "X"}
            };
```

Here for same `Name` I have one or more than one owner.

Now I want to transform this data into list based owners like below class,

```
public class ListBasedData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<string> Owners { get; set; }
    }
```

And here I am trying to do, how to grab all the owners of a name?

```
List<ListBasedData> listBasedDatas = new List<ListBasedData>();

            var groups = data.GroupBy(a => a.Name);

            foreach (var group in groups)
            {
                var a = group.Key;

                var b = group.ToList();

                listBasedDatas.Add(new ListBasedData{Name = group.Key, Owners = });
            }
```

Comment: you just iterate the `group` - it should have all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<ListBasedData> listBasedDatas = data
    .GroupBy(a => a.Name)
    .Select(grp => new ListBasedData
    {
        Name = grp.Key,
        Owners = grp.Select(x => x.Owner).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

The key is to use `Select` to perform a projection on the owners in each group, from `PlainData` to `string`.

Comment: Thanks @Johnathan Barclay. Appreciated. I have one more question on same line. Could you please help here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63956301/is-there-a-way-to-prepare-all-the-owners-data-in-one-go